# Drawing 2D text over 3D objects in Processing 3

Tags: java, 3d, 2d, processing

So I'm making a game and I want to draw 2D stuff over 3D stuff. I'm using Processing 3. How could I do this?

Comment: According to your tags, you're also using OpenGL, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to draw 2D graphics (such as UI) over 3D, you'd have to:

1. Enable depth testing before the 3D drawing starts.
2. Disable depth testing after the 3D drawing ends. Optional: also swap the shader to a simpler one, which doesn't process lighting and such.
3. Draw the 2D graphics. You can also swap the shader back now.

The code for disabling depth testing would be as simple as:

```
hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
```

The code for enabling it before the 3D drawing can be:

```
hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't use OpenGL directly. Read about [Processing](https://processing.org/)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Updated the answer to the appropiate code. I thought that it used OpenGL, which meant that it should've worked with OpenGL functions.

Comment: @John no I use the methods that are in PApplet class